# JQuery - JS - Keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

When I press any arrow or use WSAD, after the first "activation" of keydown event, there is slight delay until next one, but after that its normal. Example: When you press arrow and hold it, you move 1px, wait a bit and then start moving normally by 1px periodicly.

My code:

```
 //========== KEY LOGGING ==========
          var pressedKeys = [];

          //declare as globals coz of debug
          var x;
          var y;
          var x2;
          var y2;

          function checkMove(checkX, checkY, cSize, cSpeed, direction) {
              x = checkX - cSpeed;
              y = checkY - cSpeed;
              x2 = checkX + cSize + cSpeed;
              y2 = checkY + cSize + cSpeed;

              switch (direction) {
                  case 1:
                      // left
                      if (x > 0) {
                          return checkX - cSpeed;
                      } else {
                          return 0;
                      }
                      break;

                  case 2:
                      // up
                      if (y > 0) {
                          return checkY - cSpeed;
                      } else {
                          return 0;
                      }
                      break;

                  case 3:
                      // right
                      if (x2 < width) {
                          return checkX + cSpeed;
                      } else {
                          return width - cSize;
                      }
                      break;

                  case 4:
                      // down
                      if (y2 < height) {
                          return checkY + cSpeed;
                      } else {
                          return height - cSize;
                      }
                      break;

                  default:
                      return; // exit this handler for other keys
              }

          }

          // == KEYDOWN ==
          $(document.body).keydown(function (e) {
              pressedKeys[e.which] = true;
              $.each(playerList, function (i, currentPlayer) {
                  //player 1
                  if (currentPlayer.id == 0) {
                      //left    
                      if (pressedKeys[37] == true) {
                          currentPlayer.x = checkMove(currentPlayer.x, currentPlayer.y, currentPlayer.size, currentPlayer.speed, 1)
                      }
                      //up    
                      if (pressedKeys[38] == true) {
                          currentPlayer.y = checkMove(currentPlayer.x, currentPlayer.y, currentPlayer.size, currentPlayer.speed, 2)
                      }
                      //right    
                      if (pressedKeys[39] == true) {
                          currentPlayer.x = checkMove(currentPlayer.x, currentPlayer.y, currentPlayer.size, currentPlayer.speed, 3)
                      }
                      //down    
                      if (pressedKeys[40] == true) {
                          currentPlayer.y = checkMove(currentPlayer.x, currentPlayer.y, currentPlayer.size, currentPlayer.speed, 4)
                      }
                  }
                  //player 2
                  else if (currentPlayer.id == 1) {
                      //left    
                      if (pressedKeys[65] == true) {
                          currentPlayer.x = checkMove(currentPlayer.x, currentPlayer.y, currentPlayer.size, currentPlayer.speed, 1)
                      }
                      //up    
                      if (pressedKeys[87] == true) {
                          currentPlayer.y = checkMove(currentPlayer.x, currentPlayer.y, currentPlayer.size, currentPlayer.speed, 2)
                      }
                      //right    
                      if (pressedKeys[68] == true) {
                          currentPlayer.x = checkMove(currentPlayer.x, currentPlayer.y, currentPlayer.size, currentPlayer.speed, 3)
                      }
                      //down    
                      if (pressedKeys[83] == true) {
                          currentPlayer.y = checkMove(currentPlayer.x, currentPlayer.y, currentPlayer.size, currentPlayer.speed, 4)
                      }
                  }

                  //addplayer
                  if (pressedKeys[80] == true && id < 5) {
                      addPlayer("red", size, width / 2, height / 2);
                  }
                  //+    
                  if (pressedKeys[107] == true) {
                      currentPlayer.speed += 1;
                  }
                  //-
                  if (pressedKeys[109] == true && currentPlayer.speed > 1) {
                      currentPlayer.speed -= 1;
                  }

              });
          });

          // == KEYUP ==    
          $(document.body).keyup(function (e) {
              delete pressedKeys[e.which];
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lee mentioned it is a feature of operating systems. And the only way you can fix it is using `setInterval` function:

```
var pressedKeys = [];
$(document.body).keydown(function(e){
    if (!pressedKeys[e.which]){
        pressedKeys[e.which] = setInterval(function(){
           console.log(1); 
        }, 0);
    }
});

$(document.body).keyup(function (e) {
    if (pressedKeys[e.which]){
        clearInterval(pressedKeys[e.which]);
        delete pressedKeys[e.which];
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/claustrofob/tByzK/2/

It even gives you more control over the `keydown` callback as you can adjust the delay of `setInteval` and as a result to get better performance across browsers.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice idea. I got one more question, sometimes, when I execute too much code (add too many players at once in my case) the browser freezes, is there anyway to prevent that?

Comment: If you mean this code `if (pressedKeys[80] == true && id < 5)` try to move it outside of `$.each(playerList, function (i, currentPlayer) {` as it seems not relevant to `currentPlayer`. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mainly down to the "repeat delay" set in the keyboard settings of the operating system. In Windows 7, if you go to your control panel, then go to your keyboard settings, you will see there that you can set a delay between a single and repeated key event as well as how often the key is repeated.

Obviously since this is an O/S setting, you can't change it via the browser and neither can you change your own settings as not everyone will share those settings.

The best way is to use the keydown and keyup events along with a timer. So when a key triggers a keydown event, you set an interval timer that fires every x milliseconds with your function, then cancels the interval when keyup is triggered.